# 特定のサイトにSSLで接続する場合だけ "unable to get local issuer certificate"が出る

Tags: ruby, ssl, https

以下のように特定のサイト( https://xml.irpocket.com )に`HTTPS`で接続しようとすると`unable to get local issuer certificate`エラーが出ます。

```
require 'net/https'
url = URI('https://xml.irpocket.com')
Net::HTTP.get(url)
#=> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
from /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock'
```

ですが https://google.co.jp など他のSSL接続を使用してるサイトではエラーなく正常にページが取得されます。

「ローカルの証明書が取得できない」というエラーなら接続先を変更してもエラー内容は変わらないはずだと思うのですが、このような動作になるのは何が原因なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nslookup xml.irpocket.com`をしたところIPアドレスが３つ返ってきました。
3台にたいして`openssl s_client -connect <address>:443`で確認したところ、

ある１台

```
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Multi-Domain, CN = irpocket.com
verify return:1
read:errno=10093
```

残り２台

```
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Multi-Domain, CN = irpocket.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Multi-Domain, CN = irpocket.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
read:errno=10093
```

という結果が得られました。当該サイトはサーバーローカルに設定されている証明書に問題があるのかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど、サーバーローカルの証明書がうまくとれない時にもこのようなエラーになるんですね、勉強になります。ありがとうございました。